# Use mutex but still got concurrent map writes

Tags: go

I have a map and want to manually further sharding, the simplified code is

```
const (
    dictShardNum = 16
    dictShardSize = 1 << 28
)

type shard struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    m  map[int64]uint32
}

type dict struct {
    shards []shard
}

func newDict() *dict {
   shards := make([]shard, 0, dictShardNum)
   for i := 0; i < dictShardNum; i++ {
      shards = append(shards, shard{ m: make(map[int64]uint32) })
   }
   return &dict{ shards }
}

func (d *dict) insert(n int64) uint32 {
    shardNum := int(n % dictShardNum)
    shard := d.shards[shardNum]
    shard.mu.Lock()
    defer shard.mu.Unlock()

    tempID, ok := shard.m[n]
    if !ok {
        tempID = uint32(len(shard.m) + shardNum*dictShardSize)
        shard.m[n] = tempID   // fatal error: concurrent map writes
    }
    return tempID
}
```

When running I got `fatal error: concurrent map writes` at that line, but I did lock the mutex, not sure what's wrong with my code

Comment: Can you show us how you created the `dict`? I think it is possible that you are copying the `sync.Mutex`.

Answer (score 5):

> [Package sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)
>
> ```
> import "sync"
> ```
>
> [type Mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex)
>
> A Mutex is a mutual exclusion lock. The zero value for a Mutex is an
>   unlocked mutex.
>
> A Mutex must not be copied after first use.

---

Your code doesn't compile!

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6AwS0vOZfeP

```
25:18: undefined: n
30:24: undefined: n
33:11: undefined: n
```

If I change `v int64` to `n int64`:

> A Mutex must not be copied after first use.

```
$ go vet mutex.go
./mutex.go:26:11: assignment copies lock value to shard: command-line-arguments.shard contains sync.Mutex
$
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jExE-m11ny5

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

const (
    dictShardNum  = 16
    dictShardSize = 1 << 28
)

type shard struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    m  map[int64]uint32
}

type dict struct {
    shards []shard
}

/// a newDict function

func (d *dict) insert(n int64) uint32 {
    shardNum := int(n % dictShardNum)
    shard := d.shards[shardNum]
    shard.mu.Lock()
    defer shard.mu.Unlock()

    tempID, ok := shard.m[n]
    if !ok {
        tempID = uint32(len(shard.m) + shardNum*dictShardSize)
        shard.m[n] = tempID // fatal error: concurrent map writes
    }
    return tempID
}

func main() {}
```

---

> [Command vet](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/)
>
> Vet examines Go source code and reports suspicious constructs
>
> [Copying locks](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/#hdr-Copying_locks)
>
> Flag: -copylocks
>
> Locks that are erroneously passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is related to copy mutex values.
The dict `should` be

```
type dict struct {
    shards []*shard
}
```

All `shard`s are accessed via pointer then it won't have any issue.